# Problem Navbar Center fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign

Tags: html, navbar, center

I was setting up the nav-bar. I wrote the code but the navbar is always on the left, I don't understand why it doesn't move to the center.

```
[enter image description here][1]
```

this is my code of navbar

```html
<div class="navtabs-container">
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar mat-tab-nav-bar fxFlex fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center center">
        
        <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/"
        routerLinkActive #home="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="home.isActive">
        Home
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/accomodation"
        routerLinkActive #accomodation="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="accomodation.isActive">
        Accomodation
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/rentboat"
        routerLinkActive #rentboat="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="rentboat.isActive">
        Rent Boat
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/daytripstours"
        routerLinkActive #daytripstours="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="daytripstours.isActive">
        Activities
    </a>
    <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/foodandbeverage"
        routerLinkActive #foodandbeverage="routerLinkActive"
        [active]="foodandbeverage.isActive">
        Food &amp; Beverage
     </a>

     <a mat-tab-link routerLink="/offers"
     routerLinkActive #offers="routerLinkActive"
     [active]="offers.isActive">
     Offers
 </a>
    
    </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: You have to share your styles first. Then I can help you to improve it and centralize your navbar.

Comment: Hello , i post the navtabs.component.css
navtabs.component-theme.scss
navtabs.component.spec.ts
navtabs.component.ts

Comment: You can just set the attribute "text-align: center" for the class .navtabs-container. That's all.

Comment: i try but not working

Answer (score 0):

i fix

```html
        <nav mat-tab-nav-bar fxFlex fxLayout mat-align-tabs="center">
```